# How do I make an applescript that waits for an application to start then quits the application?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I want to make an applescript that when started, will wait for an application to open then quit out of that application.

Here is my code:

```
repeat until application "Steam" is running
    delay 4
end repeat
repeat until application "Steam" is not running
    delay 4
    quit application "Steam"
end repeat
```

what ends up happening is the program infinitely loops.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the quit command whilst it ***is*** running, not when it isn't.

```
repeat until application "Steam" is running
    delay 4
    quit application "Steam"
end repeat
```

This will wait 'forever' until Steam starts, then quit it.  It will also then close itself, having done its task.

I get the impression that's perhaps not what you really want. Nesting this is possible,

```
repeat until application "Steam" is running
    delay 4 
    repeat until application "Steam" is not running
        delay 4
        quit application "Steam"
    end repeat
end repeat
```

but setting it to constantly check 24/7 is a bit clumsy & whilst beyond my paygrade, I'm sure there's a better way, not using Applescript.

The second version, btw, will just run 'forever' until you manually quit it. You don't really need the second loop, unless for some weird reason you expect the app to disobey the quit command.